# C - Dynamically allocate an array of char

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

What is the size of dynamic memory allocated for array?
for example we have to print an array of len = 4

```
int i, n, len = 4;
char *s = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
strcpy(s, "aaabbcc");
n = strlen(s);
printf("%d", n);
```

The output should be `4` but all the time output is `7`.

Comment: strlen counts the number of chars in your string. Not related to the fact that you allocated too few bytes and you may crash your program doing that.

Comment: It is an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you have to allocate fixed size buffers for data. In your case, you allocated `len * sizeof(char)`, where `len = 4` bytes for your string.

From the documentation on [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

> char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
>
> Copy string Copies the C string pointed by source into the array
>   pointed by destination, including the terminating null character (and
>   stopping at that point).
>
> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the
>   terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

You copy a string of size 8 (`"aaabbcc"` and the implicit null terminator) into your buffer of size 4. This is what referred to as a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow); you copied a string into a buffer smaller than the string requires.

[`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) looks for a null terminator in the string to find the string size. It reads your buffer overflowed string which is why it returns 7: the size of your buffer overflowed string minus one for the null terminator.

Note that it may seem unimportant to allocate a buffer of the correct size, but it is critical to do so. An overflowed value could be overridden in memory or override other memory causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: "In C, you have to allocate fixed size buffers for data" - that is true in any language. What do you mean with "fixed size buffers"?The size to `malloc` can be a variable and VLAs have that in their name. Also there is `realloc`.

Comment: @Olaf The question refers to 'dynamic memory/allocation'. I merely mean to highlight the point that you much explicitly state the size of an allocation you are making. That is not to say that you can't `realloc` for a different sized buffer or make the allocation size dependant on a variable. From another language perspective, Python, for example, provides a layer of abstraction onto the allocations which gives the illusion of dynamic allocation; the variable is as large as you need it to be when you need it. This is untrue for C, as it requires the programmer to consciously manage memory.

Comment: As you say, Pytohn hides the allocation from the user. So from the user's perspective you cannot allocate memory, which makes the idea of allocation from that perspective irelevant. The space is "just there". Under the hood, being written in C, Python uses `malloc` etc, which makes my statement very true (similar for other languages). This proves another fact: you can very well write an abstraction in C which provides seamless resizing of objects. You just have to provide a full set of e.g. arithmetic operations. There are even libraries in C which provide that feature.

Comment: Re `realloc`: resizing an array is exactly its purpose. Not sure what you mean. Of course you can (and have to) memorise the current length some way. Typically in a variable. This is also true for `malloc`ed arrays or VLAs.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I only point out the distinction that during an instance of a particular allocation, you must specify a fixed size for the allocation. If you are building an implementation of a vector, for instance, you interact with it as if memory is dynamic. However in the implementation of the vector, at some point you will have filled the fixed buffer previously allocated. The solution will be to resize or allocate more memory to a larger size that can accommodate the new element(s). It would be making a series of fixed size allocations to create the dynamic nature.

Comment: I think we are debating a use in terminology.